# If $P(\limsup_n E_n) = 1$, is it necessarily true that $P(E_n) \to 1$?

Tags: probability-theory

I have a probability space $(\Omega,P)$ and a sequence of events $(E_n)_n$ which satisfy $P(\limsup_n E_n) = 1$. Does it necessarily follow that $P(E_n)$ approaches $1$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

The events $(E_n)_n$ are not necessarily independent. I know from the contrapositive of the Borel-Cantelli lemma that $\sum_n P(E_n) = \infty$, which is necessary but not sufficient for $P(E_n) \to 1$.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. The set $\limsup_n E_n$ consists of those points that appear in infinitely many $E_n$. So, if we wish, we can pick $E_{2n}=\Omega$ and $E_{2n+1} =\emptyset$. Then the measure of the limsup is one, but $P(E_n)$ does not converge to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

$$\begin{cases}
E_n &= \Omega \text{ for n odd}\\
E_n &= \emptyset  \text{ for n even}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I like your example :)